# How can I delete int in Pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this, how can I delete all the int in a column?

For example, the value of `column[0]['material']`, transformed from `lm792` to `lm`.

```
      material  item
index       
0   lm792         1
1   sotl085-pu01. 1
2   lm792         1
3   sotl085-pu01. 1
4   ym11-3527     1
... ... ...
135526  0         0
135527  0         0
135528  0         0
135529  0         0
135530  0         0
```

Comment: You should show what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a simple regex -

`\d` is a digit (a character in the range 0-9), and `+` means 1 or more times. So, `\d+` is 1 or more digits.

```
df['material'] = df['material'].str.replace('\d+','')
```

---

```
print(df)
material  item
0        lm   1.0
1  sotl-pu.   1.0
2        lm   1.0
3  sotl-pu.   1.0
4       ym-   1.0
5             NaN
6             NaN
7             NaN
8             NaN
9             0.0
```

Comment: @SteveHsu consider green ticking the solution so this can be closed =)